Can I vacuum seal my homemade bone broth in a Ball jar?
It appears you can purchase bone broth in cardboard containers that have a shelf-stable life for three or more months.  If this is because of the absence of air in the container, for those broths that contain no preservatives, then I should be able to vacuum seal my homemade broth in Ball jars?  I want to make larger batches and put it on the shelf without having to pressure can it.  Obviously the bone broth in cardboard boxes is not canned.

what sort of freezer space do you have?  I just cook down broth to reduce it by 1/2 or more, then freeze it in smallish containers (or even ice cube trays then put into a zipper freezer bag).  To use, just defrost and dilute.

It is not a question of the lack of air. In order to be shelf stable, they need to kill everything that might be living in the broth while creating a seal that will prevent anything else from getting in. At home this is done with high temperature (hence the need for pressure canning to exceed 100c for a prolonged period to kill those nasty little extremophiles).
Unfortunately, the only way to safely store bone broth at home would be to either pressure can it or freeze it.
There is no way to reliably mimic the low-heat methods used for shelf stable broths you see in cardboard containers at home.
For reference on the scale of the equipment needed, this is what Tetra Pak's smallest filling machine looks like.


@mdfst13, they are 2 stories tall. the safety railing on the second level is standard height. The bigger models even come with stairs attached.

Commercial canning equipment is usually also larger than a typical home kitchen, but that doesn't imply it's impossible to put marinara sauce into jars at home. The size of the commercial equipment is more a reflection of what's needed to economically process large amounts of product at scale. -- That's not to say one is able to do the equivalent of 'tetrapack' at home. Only that the commercial equipment size isn't a definitive argument against it.

I think that I see stairs in the back corner, on the left in this picture.

The big thing you'll find is that this kind of equipment is generally installed in a cleanroom, and the operators dress so as to minimize contamination. That way, once all the various parts are sterilized, they tend to stay that way.  You could do it this way at home, but it's really only economical on a large scale and at home it's way, way easier to just use a pressure canner.  Bone broth won't be affected much by the canning process anyway.

@R.M. I think you have missed my point, which is that in a home kitchen, pressure canning is the way to go. While low pressure, and even (relatively) low temperature, options exist, they are not practical in the home. I included the image less for the size and more to demonstrate the scale of complexity. (Also, I know this wasn't your point, but just so it's clear to anyone new to canning. Bone broth and marinara do not have the same canning requirements. Marinara can be water bath canned, but bone broth absolutely cannot.)

@LightBender And I think you missed my point. You presented a picture of equipment as if it was supposed to explain something. What it explains is unclear. I focused on size due to the word "smallest" being the closest thing to it you provide. But with complexity my point still stands: commercial canning lines are also complex. You could use a picture of one to "explain" it's too complex to do at home. -- So how does the picture show it's  uncopyable? Is it size? Complexity? That it's in a clean room? Something else? This answer could be improved by explicitly explaining that in the text.

While I'm sure it could be done smaller consider that you need to be able to sterilize material that can't tolerate heat.  I very much doubt that can be done without creating a pretty hazardous working environment.

@R.M. Consider the context of the OP's question (wanting a—presumably easier—alternative to pressure canning.) I felt that the image demonstrated that by any metric a low temp solution is not an easier option. It also seemed unwise to go into any further detail lest anyone mistake it for instructions and attempt it at home, which could easily kill someone if anything went wrong. For anyone truly interested, here is what the FDA has to say about the subject.
